# Run a process from a windows service as the current user

Tags: c#, windows-services

I currently have a windows service that is running under the System Account. My problem is that i need to start certain processes from within the service as the current logged on user. I have all the code etc to get the current logged on user / Active session.

My problem is that i need spawn a process as the logged on user but will not know the user credentials etc.

The service is .net compiled service and i expect that i need to use some Pinvoke methods to get a handle of one of the current users process in order to duplicate it and lunch as process with the handle.

Unfortunately i cannot find any good documentation / solution on how to implement it?

If someone is able to give me some guidance / example i would highly appreciate it.

*** Updated ***
I think i have explained this incorrectly and need to reajust according to what i actually require. I do not necessarily want to launch a new process, i just want to impersonate the logged on user. I have been so wrapped up at looking at CreateProcess etc i have lead myself down a path of create a new process as the current logged in user (which is not particularly what i want to do).

In turn i just want to run some code under the current user context (Impersonate the current Logged on user)?

Comment: What if no user has logged on?

Comment: i think you try to running window service as admin account.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option is to have background application that automatically starts when user logs on and listens to commands from your service through WCF, or thrift, or by just monitoring some file and reading command from there.

Another option is to do what you originally asked for - launch using windows API. But the code is quite scary. Here is a sample, that you can use. It will execute any command line under currently active user session, with CreateProcessInConsoleSession method:

```
internal class ApplicationLauncher
{
    public enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
    {
        TokenUser = 1,
        TokenGroups,
        TokenPrivileges,
        TokenOwner,
        TokenPrimaryGroup,
        TokenDefaultDacl,
        TokenSource,
        TokenType,
        TokenImpersonationLevel,
        TokenStatistics,
        TokenRestrictedSids,
        TokenSessionId,
        TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
        TokenSessionReference,
        TokenSandBoxInert,
        TokenAuditPolicy,
        TokenOrigin,
        MaxTokenInfoClass // MaxTokenInfoClass should always be the last enum
    }

    public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;

    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;

    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL;
    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = READ_CONTROL;

    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000;

    public const int SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF;

    public const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    public const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    public const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;

    public const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
                                           TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
                                           TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
                                           TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
                                           TOKEN_QUERY |
                                           TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
                                           TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                           TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                           TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT);

    public const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS_P | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

    public const int TOKEN_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY;

    public const int TOKEN_WRITE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                   TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                                   TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
                                   TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT;

    public const int TOKEN_EXECUTE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE;

    public const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

    public const int CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200;
    public const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;

    public const int IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
    public const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
    public const int HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
    public const int REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

    public const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

    public const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
    public const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
    public const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";

    public const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x0002;

    public const int ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

    private const uint TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;

    public static int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr lpSystemName, string lpname,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
        int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
    public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
        int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, bool DisableAllPrivileges,
        ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, int BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass,
        ref uint TokenInformation, uint TokenInformationLength);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

    public static bool CreateProcessInConsoleSession(String CommandLine, bool bElevate)
    {

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        bool bResult = false;
        uint dwSessionId, winlogonPid = 0;
        IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero, hUserTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero, hPToken = IntPtr.Zero, hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

        Debug.Print("CreateProcessInConsoleSession");
        // Log the client on to the local computer.
        dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        // Find the winlogon process
        var procEntry = new PROCESSENTRY32();

        uint hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return false;
        }

        procEntry.dwSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(procEntry); //sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, ref procEntry) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        String strCmp = "explorer.exe";
        do
        {
            if (strCmp.IndexOf(procEntry.szExeFile) == 0)
            {
                // We found a winlogon process...make sure it's running in the console session
                uint winlogonSessId = 0;
                if (ProcessIdToSessionId(procEntry.th32ProcessID, ref winlogonSessId) &&
                    winlogonSessId == dwSessionId)
                {
                    winlogonPid = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (Process32Next(hSnap, ref procEntry) != 0);

        //Get the user token used by DuplicateTokenEx
        WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, ref hUserToken);

        var si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
        var tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        var luid = new LUID();
        hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, false, winlogonPid);

        if (
            !OpenProcessToken(hProcess,
                TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY
                | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID | TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_WRITE, ref hPToken))
        {
            Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession OpenProcessToken error: {0}",
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }

        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(IntPtr.Zero, SE_DEBUG_NAME, ref luid))
        {
            Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession LookupPrivilegeValue error: {0}",
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }

        var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

        if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa,
                (int) SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int) TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                ref hUserTokenDup))
        {
            Debug.Print(
                String.Format(
                    "CreateProcessInConsoleSession DuplicateTokenEx error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                    Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            CloseHandle(hUserToken);
            CloseHandle(hPToken);
            return false;
        }

        if (bElevate)
        {
            //tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
            //tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tp.Privileges = new int[3];
            tp.Privileges[2] = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            tp.Privileges[1] = luid.HighPart;
            tp.Privileges[0] = luid.LowPart;

            //Adjust Token privilege
            if (
                !SetTokenInformation(hUserTokenDup, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenSessionId, ref dwSessionId,
                    (uint) IntPtr.Size))
            {
                Debug.Print(
                    String.Format(
                        "CreateProcessInConsoleSession SetTokenInformation error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                //CloseHandle(hProcess);
                //CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                //CloseHandle(hPToken);
                //CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
                //return false;
            }
            if (
                !AdjustTokenPrivileges(hUserTokenDup, false, ref tp, Marshal.SizeOf(tp), /*(PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)*/
                    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                int nErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                if (nErr == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
                {
                    Debug.Print(
                        String.Format(
                            "CreateProcessInConsoleSession AdjustTokenPrivileges error: {0} Token does not have the privilege.",
                            nErr));
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Print(String.Format("CreateProcessInConsoleSession AdjustTokenPrivileges error: {0}", nErr));
                }
            }
        }

        uint dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
        IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserTokenDup, true))
        {
            dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        // Launch the process in the client's logon session.
        bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup, // client's access token
            null, // file to execute
            CommandLine, // command line
            ref sa, // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
            ref sa, // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
            false, // handles are not inheritable
            (int) dwCreationFlags, // creation flags
            pEnv, // pointer to new environment block 
            null, // name of current directory 
            ref si, // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            out pi // receives information about new process
            );
        // End impersonation of client.

        //GetLastError should be 0
        int iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        //Close handles task
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
        CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
        CloseHandle(hPToken);

        return (iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser == 0) ? true : false;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int Process32First(uint hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int Process32Next(uint hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(uint dwFlags, uint th32ProcessID);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hSnapshot);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern uint WTSQueryUserToken(uint SessionId, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, ref uint pSessionId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, // handle to process
        int DesiredAccess, // desired access to process
        ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    #region Nested type: LUID

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID
    {
        public int LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }

    #endregion

    //end struct

    #region Nested type: LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public int Attributes;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: PROCESSENTRY32

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESSENTRY32
    {
        public uint dwSize;
        public readonly uint cntUsage;
        public readonly uint th32ProcessID;
        public readonly IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
        public readonly uint th32ModuleID;
        public readonly uint cntThreads;
        public readonly uint th32ParentProcessID;
        public readonly int pcPriClassBase;
        public readonly uint dwFlags;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public readonly string szExeFile;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: PROCESS_INFORMATION

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int Length;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL

    private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous = 0,
        SecurityIdentification = 1,
        SecurityImpersonation = 2,
        SecurityDelegation = 3,
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: STARTUPINFO

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public String lpReserved;
        public String lpDesktop;
        public String lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        internal int PrivilegeCount;
        //LUID_AND_ATRIBUTES
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        internal int[] Privileges;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: TOKEN_TYPE

    private enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation = 2
    }

    #endregion

    // handle to open access token
}
```

Comment: This looks to be what i am looking for.. I will read over the code which is nicely commented and looks straight forward..

Comment: Interesting, the sample code does *exactly* what [this post on the Windows SDK Support Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx) says you should "never, never and never do": stealing the access token of the explorer process running on the interactive user's desktop, opening that process's access token, and creating a new process with this token.

Comment: That code was exactly what I was looking for.  Created a new class.  Dropped this code in, made the call and it worked first attempt.  Thank yo so much for posting this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've only replaced "explorer.exe" with "winlogon.exe" so my executed app jumps on top of other windows, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Does this still work?  I am only able to get it open an application with "administrator" access only.... what I would like is for the application to run as the logged in user.   Possible?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Win10; Error code 1314

Comment: @alex what is the role of the `Elevate` parameter in this functions `CreateProcessInConsoleSession(String CommandLine, bool bElevate)`?

Answer (score 13):

As is so common with these types of questions about Windows services, you're operating in the mindset of a single-user operating system. The whole reason you decided to write your app as a service was because you were running into conflicts between your mental model of a single-user OS and the reality of a multi-user OS. Unfortunately, a service didn't solve all of your problems and now you're trying to figure out how to accomplish step two in the ultimately-doomed hacked design.

The fact is, you cannot be guaranteed that there ***is*** a "logged on user". If no one has logged on to the workstation, there will be no one logged on, yet your service will still be running.

Even if you somehow got past this by ensuring that someone will *always* be logged on (impossible), then you would run into the situation where *multiple* users are logged on. Then which one should your service start the process as? Should it just pick one of them randomly?

And is it necessary in your case to distinguish between users logged on locally to the console and those who are logged on remotely? Remember that remote users won't have a local console.

If you could somehow get past all of these hurdles (unfortunately, probably by burying your head in the sand and continuing to pretend that Windows is a single-user OS), you could make use of the [`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835.aspx) function to obtain the current session ID, the [`WTSQueryUserToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840.aspx) function to obtain the user token corresponding to that session ID, and then finally the [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) function to launch your process in the context of that user. If there is one. And they have the appropriate privileges. And the physical console is not attached to a dummy session. And you're not running a server SKU that allows multiple active console sessions. And…

If you could decide on a particular user whose account you wish to use to start the auxiliary process, you could log on that user, manipulate their user token, execute the process, and finally close the process and log out the user. The [`CreateProcessWithLogonUser` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx) wraps up a lot of this drudgery for you, making the code a lot more svelte. But appearances can be deceiving, and this still has some *massive* security implications that you probably do not completely understand if you're asking this question in the first place. And you really cannot afford to not understand security risks like this.

Besides, users that are logged in with [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) (which is done for you automatically when you use the `CreateProcessWithLogonUser` function) lack a window station and desktop on which they can launch interactive processes. So if the process you wish to launch in the context of that user will show any kind of UI, you're out of luck. Windows will kill your app as soon as it tries to access a desktop for which it lacks the requisite permissions. There is no way, from a Windows service, to obtain the handle of a desktop that will be useful to you (which goes a long way towards explaining the general rule you probably already know, that services cannot display any type of UI).

Comment: I really liked "ultimately-doomed". But `CreateProcessWithLogonW` won't help Him since he doesn't have user credentials.

Comment: The windows service was originally designed to accept incoming messages and process them as requested (Using a message system from a remote applciaiton into the service). The service is running as intentionally but extra specification are now required.  I Unfortnuneatly certain Api need to be invoked as a current user and hence the reason why now its a requirement. I understand the security risks but this will only be invoking a couple of API that are defined for CU / Active users. I can and the service ensure that there is a user logged onto the machine, if not it will report back.

Comment: What is it going to "report" to? There is no user logged in! And what are these APIs that you need to invoke? Why do they require invocation as a particular user? It seems like therein lies the real solution to your problem.

Comment: The remote application is run on any domain machine, which allow connection into the service, therefore the service will report back to the application as required. The service is acting as a client application as such, that allow to invoke elevated commands as requested. As i said before the specification of the applications have slightly changed and now certain requirement need to be invoked as the current user. Example Certain SCCM Api require to be run as the current user as per MSDN documentation. Another thought is as Alex suggested which is a standalone process on user logon..

Comment: Or, you could just use this code, which is super easy to use and works just fine. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite