# Run process as administrator from service

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a service installed and I need to start it's own executable from it with administrative access without the user interaction (the user has agreeded to do so when installing the service). In the app I check if I'm in a service and if not (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher fails) it will do admin stuff.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635587/run-process-from-a-windows-service-as-the-current-user-with-administrative-privi) does not help, the app already is set (because it's a service as well) as admin but it will run without admin rights.

This is a remote deskop support application based on Windows RDP service and if it is not run as administrator, then I cannot interact with UAC presented in the remote desktop in case some other app is to be run as admin.

I'm trying this (error handling removed):

```
    PWTS_SESSION_INFO w;
    DWORD c = 0;
    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &w, &c);
    DWORD sid = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(w[i].pWinStationName, L"console") == 0)
        {
            sid = w[i].SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }
    WTSFreeMemory(w);
    HANDLE t = 0;
    WTSQueryUserToken(sid, &t);

    HANDLE pt = 0;
    TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN   linkedToken = { 0 };   
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(linkedToken);
    GetTokenInformation(t,
        TokenLinkedToken,
        &linkedToken,
        dwSize, &dwSize)

    DuplicateTokenEx(linkedToken.LinkedToken,TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,  NULL,   SecurityImpersonation,  TokenPrimary,&pt);

    SetTokenInformation(pt, TokenSessionId, (void*)&sid, sizeof(sid));          
    CreateProcessAsUser(pt, 0, fw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &sInfo, &pInfo);
    ...
```

This new process is started without admin privileges although it's the very same executable that has the manifest set to the admin level.

Comment: the linked token can not exist (in case user not admin). or user is built-in admin. or no uac. also you not need set `TokenSessionId` - it already correct. also you not close (or drop this code handles). however in case linked token exist and it elevated - this code start process with admin