# Limitations of Windows Service on run the .exe file

Tags: c#, windows-services

I 'm trying to get Certificates from a external device using windows-Service . 
how should a handle limitations for current user?

I have an .exe file that get certificates from an extra device(Token) and it work correctly . but when it called from my windows service using WCF , it doesn't show me all certificates . 
Does it make a limitation for user or app?

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + 
        @"GetCertificate.exe";
        log.Info("LaunchCommandLineApp basePath is : " + 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        log.Info("LaunchCommandLineApp path is : " + path);
        ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION prcInf = new 
        ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(path + " -Verb runAs", 
        out prcInf);
        log.Info("After StartProcessAndBypassUAC");
    }
```

Comment: The Windows service will most probably run on another user account, usually LocalSystem or LocalService.

Comment: It is LocalSystem right now , and i tried LocalService . but it didn't work .

Comment: You wrote something about "current user" in your first sentence - this would then be the LocalService user, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is . And i noticed that the file was not executed by the current user of the system . 
Windows service creates a user to install, which is not the real user of the system

Comment: There might be no, one or many (on terminal server) interactive sessions at any time. So what is the "real user"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is `Windows Service` `User Account` that cause your exe run as that user not current user. [read more about `Windows Service` user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/service-user-accounts).

And for [Run a process from a windows service as the current user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383684/run-a-process-from-a-windows-service-as-the-current-user)