# What approach do you recommend for running an application in the background on a Windows machine, considering the context of a specific user?

Tags: windows, windows-services, background-task

I aim to execute my application in the background on a user's laptop. The application relies on user-specific settings, including access to certain user files. Therefore, it needs to run on a per-user basis.
User is going to communicate with the application via a separate WPF application using HTTP requests.

I initially explored the Windows Service approach, but my research indicates that it might not be the most effective solution for achieving a per-user approach (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384081/22337885).

Considering this, I'm seeking advice on alternative methods or best practices to run my application in the background, ensuring it functions on a per-user basis with access to user-specific settings and files. I would appreciate if you could share your thoughts and/or experience.

I've already tried to research some specific examples of the same case as I have. Everything that I could find so far points to using Windows Services.