Launching WPF GUI app from Background service
My situation is as follows:
On an unsupervised Windows 10 machine I have a .NET Framework 4.8 WPF GUI application MyApp running in the foreground and a .NET 8 grpc background service responsible for updating the GUI app on demand. I am struggling with launching MyApp after updating it. Currently, the app starts without showing a window. I can launch the window manually by clicking some button in the NotifyIcon (which is showing), but the Window does not open as usual when simply double-clicking the app icon.
I already verified that the background Launcher service is running in the user's session 1.
My Launcher service .csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

My code to launch MyApp:
using Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "path\to\MyApp.exe";
process.Start();

What changes would I need to make to get this working?
My last resort would be to simply reboot the PC, using a shortcut in shell:startup works just fine. Also, MyApp launches with the GUI if I paste the code above into a console application and run it.
For clarification, here is a rough sketch of my architecture:


What do you mean by "background service", exactly?

i added an image above to clarify.

...that doesn't really answer my question.

It is basically an ASP.NET application listening on a TCP port for gRPC commands to launch the MyApp application. I set the  to WinExe so that the ASP-Application starts without a console window and runs invisibly to the user in the background.

The following may be of interest: UseShellExecute

tried that one already, did not make a difference unfortunately.

Try searching for impersonate user.

Is this a Windows service attempting to run a user desktop application?  You'll need to "steal" the current console session token if that's what you're talking about.  Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383684/run-a-process-from-a-windows-service-as-the-current-user
